# how to add a context menu to a list item in xamarin UWP app?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, uwp

I have the following xaml code:

```
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GraphTutorial.Models"
         Title="Shared Document Library"
         x:Class="GraphTutorial.SPDocumentLibraryContentsPage">

    ...
    ...

     <ListView x:Name="SharedDocumentList"
                  HasUnevenRows="true"
                  Margin="10,10,10,10"
                  ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Margin="10,10,10,10">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Path=Id}"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   FontSize="Medium" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Path=WebUrl}"
                                   FontSize="Small" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.Resources>
                <MenuFlyout x:Name="DocumentActions">
                    <FlyoutItem x:Name="Edit"  Text="Edit" />
                    <FlyoutItem x:Name="Remove" Text="Remove"    Click="Remove_Click" />
                </MenuFlyout>
            </ListView.Resources>
        </ListView>
```

I'm presently getting the following error message on the  line:

> Error XLS0414 The type 'MenuFlyout' was not found. Verify that you are
> not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies
> have been built.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

I also have tried this:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GraphTutorial.ContextMenu"  
         Title="Shared Document Library"
         x:Class="GraphTutorial.SPDocumentLibraryContentsPage">

        <ListView x:Name="SharedDocumentList"
                  HasUnevenRows="true"
                  Margin="10,10,10,10"
                  ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Margin="10,10,10,10">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Path=Id}"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   FontSize="Medium" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Path=WebUrl}"
                                   FontSize="Small" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                        <MenuItem Text="Add" Clicked="Add_Clicked"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Text="Delete" Clicked="Delete_Clicked"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Text="Edit" Clicked="Edit_Clicked">
                    </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

But this returns the error:

> XLS0415 The attachable property 'ContextActions' was not found in type
> 'ViewCell'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error XLS0414 The type 'MenuFlyout' was not found. Verify that you are
> not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies
> have been built.

From document [MenuFlyout Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.menuflyout?view=winrt-22000),we know that class `MenuFlyout`  is a class in uwp, so we can't use it in xamarin.

If you want to add a context menu to a list item in `xamarin UWP`,you can refer to the following code:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" Margin="20" ItemSelected="OnListItemSelected">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Margin="20,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
                    <Image Source="check.png" HorizontalOptions="End" IsVisible="{Binding Done}" />
                </StackLayout>

                <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                    <MenuItem Text="Delete"
                                  Clicked="OnDeleteClicked"/>
                </ViewCell.ContextActions>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In page.xaml.cs

```
    void OnDeleteClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TodoItem itemToDelete = ((sender as MenuItem).BindingContext as TodoItem);
        // other code
    }
```

For more detail, you can check:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/menuitem

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/menuitem#cross-platform-context-menu-behavior

Comment: Hi.  So this is pretty similar / basically the same as the second example i tried - listed under Edit 1.  But I'm getting an error as (now) shown in the Edit 1 section.

Comment: to get the code to work, i just had to define the context action before the actual stacklayout - which I changed to grid.